# Can the '-' character, as is, be an alias in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make `bash` alias the '-' character, but this does not work, e.g.,

```
 % alias "-"=date
 bash: alias: -=: invalid option
```

can this be done? and if we are at it, how about `alias '='=date` ?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you want depends on shell-specific extensions; even when the POSIX standard *does* specify alias behavior (which is only the case for shells implementing both XSI and user portability extensions), the set of allowed names is not required to include either `-` or `=`:

> [3.10 Alias Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_10)
>
> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set and any of the following characters: '!', '%', ',', '@'.
>
> Implementations may allow other characters within alias names as an extension.

---

That said, when defining an alias in bash, `--` can be used to cause subsequent arguments not to be parsed as options (per [POSIX syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) entry #10):

```
alias -- -=date
```

Another option available in practice with bash (tested on both 3.2.57(1) and 4.3.46(1), but not required by the POSIX standard to be supported with these names) is to define functions:

```
$ =() { date "$@"; }
$ -() { date "$@"; }
$ =
Sat Aug 13 18:12:37 CDT 2016
$ -
Sat Aug 13 18:12:08 CDT 2016
```

Again, this goes beyond the set of names required by POSIX:

> [2.9.5 Function Definition Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)
>
> The format of a function definition command is as follows:
>
> ```
> fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
> ```
>
> The function is named *fname*; **the application shall ensure that it is a name** (see the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 3.230, Name). **An implementation may allow other characters in a function name as an extension.** The implementation shall maintain separate name spaces for functions and variables.
>
> [3.230 Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_230)
>
> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.

...and, thus, being defined neither by POSIX nor by bash's own documentation, may be subject to change in future releases.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an alias with the name `-` like this:

```
alias -- -=date
```

I'm not aware of any way of defining an alias named `=`.

Comment: That appears to be an undocumented feature.